# Brightness of three parallel light bulbs

Tags: circuit-analysis

Three lights are connected in parallel across a 120V source. If one of the light burns out, then remaining two will light,

a. will not light

b. with the same brightness

c. brighter

d. dimmer

If one light burns out , overall load R will increase(since three light were in parallel) which should lead decrease in current & hence other two lights will be dimmed but the ans is 'same brightness'. What's wrong with my logic & why exactly we can't apply this logic?

OR

this is completely related to Electromagnetic theory for light where brightness is related to applied voltage to accelerate electrons which emits light when falls from Higher energy level to lower level?

Comment: Consider: What is the voltage across the remaining working lights?

Comment: since they are in parallel, voltage will be the same across all the light but when one light burns out, shouldn't current decrease even though voltage across them is constant?

Comment: What determines the current through one light?

Comment: Since Voltage across it & Resistance of light don't change current will also not change & hence they'll continue to light with the same brightness. correct me if I'm wrong? @PeterBennett

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each bulb runs an independent current loop to a constant voltage source.
If one is off, it does not affect the brightness or voltage or current of any other loop.

Each loop current is limited by the effective resistance of the hot bulb.

But the total of all 3 loop currents is reduced 1/3 for the one burnt out bulb.

- There is no secondary electron emission or drop in quantum energy.
- This is pure thermal excitation of free electrons in a conductor, tungsten wire , elevated in temp by power dissipation (V*I)
- It has a large positive  temperature coefficient that  raises the filament resistance 10 fold
- It does this by quickly rising from room temp to about 3000 deg Kelvin (3000K).
- The temp. is limited somewhat by the surface area of the glass bulb in air as the filament heats up in an inert gas. (hint a much larger glass bulb of same power lasts longer) but more so, by convection air cooling.
- If the bulb is enclosed in another small glass ball, it gets a bit hotter and every 10 deg rise above this temperature tungsten electrons start burning off at faster rate and its time to burn out gets reduced in half. (Arhenius Law of chemistry)

The bulb stays on there as long as the constant voltage is applied.

You can run some experiments and try to prove Arhenius effects by using a light dimmer and temperature  probe and see if you can double the life by reducing the filament temperature by 10 deg C. This doesn't mean if you drop the temp by 1000'C it will last last for 2^100th times more hours because other defect rates creep in.

Now how many engineers does take to change a light bulb?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the 120V source is an ideal voltage source.  The overall load resistance increases as you have 2 bulbs in parallel instead of 3, so current at the source decreases.  However, since the bulbs are connected in parallel to an ideal voltage source, the two remaining bulbs see the same voltage as before, hence they pass the same current and dissipate the same power, hence they continue to burn at the same brightness.

If the voltage source was not ideal - i.e. it has a nonzero source impedance - then the brightness would increase (think of it like a voltage divider - larger R gets a bigger slice of the voltage, more voltage means more current and more power, means brighter bulbs).

With incandescent bulbs, the brightness is related to temperature, which will be related to power dissipation.  It's actually a bit of a complex relationship - the resistance of the filament will change with temperature, the heat flow out of the filament will also change with temperature, and the "light" out of the bulb is actually black body radiation from the hot filament, and so will change in wavelength and intensity with temperature.